# Add cost in a div

Tags: jquery, html

I have created images with a cost attribute like

```
 <img src="http://www.macnetwork.org/images/icon_linkedIn.png" cost="280" alt=''/>
```

Here i have various img tags in each cost will be added. But when i select a img its cost has to be added in a `<div>` named as `.cost`

HTML Here

```
 <div id="main">

<img src="http://www.small-icons.com/stock-icons/small-toolbar40.gif" cost="100" alt=''/>
 <img src="http://www.homeworldbusiness.com/media/icons/icon_mini_linkedin.png" cost="200" alt=''/>
 <img src="http://www.driscoll-const.com/images/skin/feed_icon.png" cost="300" alt=''/>
 <img src=" http://www.isos.com/sites/default/files/icon_images/cabling-small.png" cost="400" alt=''/>


 </div>
<div id="secondary">

<img src="http://www.macnetwork.org/images/icon_linkedIn.png" cost="280" alt=''/>
<img src="http://www.macnetwork.org/images/icon_rss.png" cost="140" alt=''/>
<img src="http://www.gogrid.com/gg/images/products/gg_prod_icon.png" cost="80" alt=''/>
<img src="http://www.lateralpaymentsolutions.com/images/contact_small_icon.jpg" cost="20" alt=''/>
 </div> 


 <div id="preview_section" style="clear:both">
 <div class="cost"></div>
<div id="main_img"></div>
  <div id="secondary_img"></div>
 </div>
```

In this cost div i have to add and subtract the values of each image selected.

If  **Image 1** in main div and **Image 2** in secondary div is selected the cost should be  as **240**

Like wise when the images is changed its previous cost has to be reduced and the selected image cost should be added.

I tried to change text in my script

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#main img").click(function(){
          var src = $(this).attr('src');
          $("#main_img").css("background-image",'url('+src+')');

          var cost = $(this).attr("cost");
          $(".cost").text(cost);
      });



       $("#secondary img").click(function(){
        var src1 = $(this).attr('src');
        $("#secondary_img").css("background-image",'url('+src1+')');

        var cost = $(this).attr("cost");
       $(".cost").text(cost);
      });


 });
```

How can i add or subtract values in this situation using jquery....
I Have made a [**fiddle**](http://jsbin.com/igopoc/1/)

Comment: I dont think you should add attributes like that. I would use "data-cost='300'" and the use the .data() from jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most easy way is to store the separate costs. Then update the global cost variable appropriately and recalculate the total cost:

```
cost1 = parseInt($(this).attr("cost"));
var totalCost = cost1 + cost2;
$(".cost").text(totalCost);
```

Note: that you need the `parseInt()` function to convert the cost strings to integers.

Note2: there are probably other (depending on your actual requirements even better?) methods as well. For example, you can use selectors to find the selected images so you do not have to store the costs values in (global) variables.

See [updated fiddle](http://jsbin.com/igopoc/3/).

Comment: If we gave praseInt a string of '0' how would you recommend making it into a price structure. For example: 0.00. Even using praseFloat like I have below would equal to 0.0?

Comment: The example showed only 'integer costs' so I used `parseInt`, but changing it to `parseFloat` is obvious enough. (Note: It is parseInt not praseInt, you also made this typo in your answer)

Comment: I do it all the time as you can tell from my comment above. All changed now lol.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because you are using text and aren't using any additions. So maybe use a function to work out the cost?

```
function workOutCost(updatedPrice){
    var newPrice = Math(parseFloat($('.cost').innerHTML)+updatePrice);
    $('.cost').HTML(newPrice);
}
```

Comment: Your method keeps on adding additional costs, which is not what the OP desires

Comment: @Veger How? You'd have to call the function in order to comply? Once called it doesn't run again unless you call it multiple times using a `setInterval` Function.

Comment: The user could select other items, as shown in the example fiddle of the question

Answer (score 0):

Parse the cost and store the main and secondary cost in separate variables. That way you can easily calculate the cost when one image changes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var cost1 = 0, cost2 = 0;

  $("#main img").click(function(){
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $("#main_img").css("background-image",'url('+src+')');

    cost1 = parseInt($(this).attr("cost"), 10);
    updateCost();
  });

  $("#secondary img").click(function(){
    var src1 = $(this).attr('src');
    $("#secondary_img").css("background-image",'url('+src1+')');

    cost2 = parseInt($(this).attr("cost"), 10);
    updateCost();
  });

  function updateCost(){
    $(".cost").text(cost1 + cost2);
  }

});
```